# Using Firebase Realtime Database node keys as document ID's in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am in the process of migrating my Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore. Ideally, I need to keep the same Realtime Database node keys that have been generated using `push()` and use it as the document ID in Firestore, but is this safe to do so?

I have read information at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices and I am still unsure whether this will be safe. I am aware that auto generated document IDs in Cloud Firestore are in a different format to those automatically generated in Realtime Database.

Am I likely to run into problems by using by using Realtime Database generated keys such as: **-M_NHw525_IxMqiGPUvd** as the document ID in Cloud Firestore?

I really appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore is sensitive to hot spots in its writing process, meaning that write throughput is best when the writes are randomly distributed across the address space. In other words: if the IDs of the documents being written, and the values that are being written to the indexes, are randomly distributed.

Firebase Realtime Database push IDs start with an encoded timestamp, so they are definitely **not** randomly distributed. They are (by design) largely sequential: subsequent calls to `push()` typically leads to keys that are next to each other. This is exactly what they were designed for in Realtime Database, but it doesn't meet the requirement of a random distribution that is needed for maximizing write throughput in Firestore.

Whether you'll run into problems when using existing push keys for your Firestore writes really depends on the implementation. For example, during a data migration you'll want to be ready to throttle the writes (sooner) when they're not randomly distributed. Hopefully the above helps you to know what to keep an eye out for when performing the data migration.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I'm just a bit confused about the part where you mention throttling the writes. Do you mean I should not transfer all the data at once? I have around 1000 users data to transfer but going forward I will be using auto generated IDs for Firestore.

Comment: During migration, you'll probably want to keep an eye on these limits: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions. After migration, you're less likely to hit those.

Comment: Hey @HarryCarter1995 Anything else needed here?

Comment: Hi Frank, Just one more question, do you think it would be better for me to store the realtime database key in a document field in firestore rather than storing it as the document ID? By doing that I should still be able to query the field that contains the realtime database key whilst at the same time being able to use firestores random ID for the doc ID?